# Adding NSMutableDictionary to NSMutableArray at specific index ?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I am trying to add NSMutableDictionary into NSMutableArray on a specific index

The NSMutableArray is already filled the data is coming from the webservice, but i want

to add another dictionary in my array on a 0 index.

**But I'm kind of stuck here :**

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: ' -[JKArray insertObject:atIndex:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'
```

**My code is:**

> on .h file

```
@property (strong, nonatomic)NSMutableArray *cityArray;

@property (strong, nonatomic)NSMutableDictionary *cityDict;

.m file:

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    self.cityArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

self.cityDict  = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"All Cities",@"key1", nil];

    NSLog(@"City Dict=> %@", cityDict);
}


-(void)ConnectionDidFinishLoading:(NSString *)responseString :(NSString *)serviceName{

        self.dealsDict = [responseString objectFromJSONString];

        self.cityArray = [self.dealsDict objectForKey:@"Cities"];

        [self.cityArray addObject:[self.cityDict copy]];

        [self.cityArray addObject:self.cityDict];

        [self.cityArray objectAtIndex:0];

        [self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

Please Help

Thanks.

Comment: I don't see where you use `insertObject:atIndex:`. Could you post this part of code?

Comment: @Zhans, no i didn't use insertObject:atIndex: -_-

Comment: I'm sorry :D. I think trouble in `self.cityArray = [self.dealsDict objectForKey:@"Cities"];` try `initWithArray:` method:)

Comment: @Zhans yeah you right i must have used initWithArray Thanks for your help its working now :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should try using `arrayWithObjects`. You are not going on the right track. 
I am unable to understand the usage of `[self.cityArray objectAtIndex:0];`

Try this:

```
 NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
 NSMutableArray *cities = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[dict objectForKey:@"cities"]];
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: You are right that was the mistake in my code i must have used initWithArray Thanks its working :)

Comment: CodeBug: lhr lhr hai ;)

Comment: No doubt :) Lhr Lhr Hay :)

Answer (score 0):

In case your `cityArray` already having an object, then try this:

```
[cityArray insertObject:[self.dealsDict objectForKey:@"Cities"] atIndex:0];
```

But your `cityArray is` empty then try this:

```
[cityArray addObject:[self.dealsDict objectForKey:@"Cities"]]
```